# Design algorithm of upload huge text files and compare lines to mySql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, algorithm, file-upload

i need some help to designing effectively algorithm (**i dont need you to write me any code!**).

i build some PHP website.

the users will upload to my website a big files (200mb+). this files is like a big tables.

i need to compare every line to mySql.

if there is **no match** between the line to the mySql table, i need to delete this line from the input file.

---

**for example:**

input file:

```
chr     pos     info              // columns
b       12      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
b       13      cccccc
c       100     fffffffffff
```

mySql table:

```
chr     pos              // columns
a       10
a       12
b       12
c       100
c       18
```

if the `chr` **and** `pos` in a line in input file, **not exist** in a row in mySql- it will delete this line from the input file.

so the new input file will be:

```
chr     pos     info              // columns
b       12      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
c       100     fffffffffff
```

---

would you have any idia for effective way with a good runtime to do it?

i dont need you to write me the code, i just need to understand the algorithm.

**algorithms that i try to do:**

1. upload the files to the server, and then upload the files to a temp mySql table with `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`, and then to use regular sql queries to compare the rows.
2. upload the files to the server, and then make the file to an huge 2D array, and then compare every row in the array to mySql.
3. upload the file to the server and while it uploading, compare every line that uploaded to mySql.

i fined the **first** algorithm as better then the **seconed**. i didnt try the **third** yet.

Comment: Any huge 2d array is going to demand a large amount of PHP memory, so is likely to cause many problems because typically PHP memory is limited

Comment: But doing this all from a web request is going to be slow with large volumes of data.... use a web request to upload the file, then trigger a background task to actually do the file/database checking so that the user isn't left waiting and wondering what's happening

Comment: It appears that you're doing a basic diff algorithm but you're using PHP and a relational database to query the changes. @MarkBaker has a valid point there - just upload the file and use a background service that will find the differences and delete what you don't need. However, I personally don't think that MySQL is a good choice for this task. It's a relational database, and since you didn't describe into detail what exactly you're doing - I just don't see how a relational database helps there, it brings a lot of overhead. If I were you, I'd explain the entire task here instead of just parts